# How do I handle no existing values in a scala for yield loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, xml-parsing, yield

I'm pull parsing a xml file that might have or might not have an element called `<Popular>`
that resides within the element `<EName>`

example:

```
<Info>
<Enterprise>
<EName>
<Legal>Cool company</Legal>
</EName>
</Enterprise>
<Enterprise>
<EName>
<Legal>Cool company2</Legal>
<Popular>The company 2</Popular>
</EName>
</Enterprise>
</Info>
```

I use **scala scales xml** like this:

```
val Info = NoNamespaceQName("Info")
val Enterprise = NoNamespaceQName("Enterprise")
val EName = NoNamespaceQName("EName")
val Legal = NoNamespaceQName("Legal")
val Popular = NoNamespaceQName("Popular")

val EnterprisePath = List(Info, Enterprise)

    val itr =  iterate(EnterprisePath, xml)
    for {
      enterprise <- itr
      enterpriseName <- enterprise \* EName \* Legal
      enterprisePopularName <- enterprise \* EName \* Popular 
    } {
      // Do fun stuff
      Logger.info("enterprise: "+enterpriseName + " "+enterprisePopularName)
}
```

What happens is that when the Popular element doesn't exist, the for statement is not fulfilled and the yield statement is not executed.

What I would like is to check the element first and if the Popular element is empty, set enterprisePopularName to an empty string

Something like:

```
<- if((enterprise \* EName \* Popular)) enterprise \* EName \* Popular else ""
```

But I can't figure it out. I guess it's because I'm a scala newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Impredicatives answer will work, but `Seq` has a nice little method called `padTo`, which you can use to ensure, that there are at least n values inside of the sequence. It takes two params `length: Int` and `elem: B`, where `B` is a subtype of the type your `Seq` contains. So in your case it would be:

```
for {
  enterprise <- itr
  enterpriseName <- enterprise \* EName \* Legal
  enterprisePopularName <- (enterprise \* EName \* Popular).padTo(1, reasonableDefaultValue)
}
```

Comment: Does `\*` produce an Option? I would expect a `Seq`.

Comment: Nice - I hadn't seen `padTo` before.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I am not familiar with 'scales', so details here may be wrong. In particular, you may find:

- `\*` does not return a `Seq` - it might return an `Iterable`, in which case just replace `Seq` with `Iterable`, or some custom collection, in which case you'll need to work out how to translate the below method.
- Probably, the sequence returned is of type `Seq[Node]` or similar, rather than `Seq[String]` - you'll need to wrap the default value as a node, or else transform the sequence (using `.map(_.toString)`) before applying the default.

I'm assuming here that the `\*` returns some kind of sequence (Scala's `Seq`). What we want is a method that takes a `Seq` and a default value and, if the `Seq` is empty, produces the default value. Note that this is just a case of writing the equivalent of `Option`'s `orElse` or `getOrElse` methods.

Here's one way we could do it:

```
def orIfEmpty[A](xs : Seq[A], default : A) : Seq[A] = 
  if (xs.isEmpty) Seq(default) else xs
```

And now we can use this in the comprehension:

```
enterprisePopularName <- orIfEmpty(enterprise \* EName \* Popular, "")
```